# How to add math/subscript in geom_bracket in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I there!

I want to include a label with subscript in `geom_bracket` in `ggplot2`. I tried in different ways, but no one worked (attempts in the comments):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = vs, y = disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_bracket(xmin = .25, xmax = .75, y.position = 250
               ,label = paste0("p_b<", format(0.06, nsmall = 3))
               # ,label = paste0(expression(p[b]), "<", format(0.06, nsmall = 3))
               # ,label = TeX(paste0("p_b<", format(0.06, nsmall = 3)))
               )
```

What I got:

[image]

Subscript does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`geom_bracket()` (which is from `ggpubr` not `ggplot2`) uses an argument to specify whether the label is an expression or text, so you can do:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = vs, y = disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_bracket(xmin = .25, xmax = .75, y.position = 250,
               label = "p[b] < 0.06", type = "expression")
```

[image]

Comment: Tks Brow! You saved my day! I forgot that! I spent too much time on it..

Comment: To add more info to the answer: In order to keep the formatting (whit trailing zeros) I had to do: `label = paste0("p[b] < ", deparse(format(0.06, nsmall = 3)))`